# Group mysql result into an php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an result fetched by mysql join like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [job_card_id] => 1
            [repair_order_id] => 1
            [customer_request] => test customer request
            [qty] => 5
            [registration_no] => DL 17U 7113

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [job_card_id] => 1
            [repair_order_id] => 2
            [customer_request] => test customer request1
            [qty] => 5
            [registration_no] => DL 17U 7113
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [job_card_id] => 2
            [repair_order_id] => 4
            [customer_request] => test customer request
            [qty] => 5
            [registration_no] => DL 17U 6111
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [job_card_id] => 2
            [repair_order_id] => 5
            [customer_request] => test customer request1
            [qty] => 5
            [registration_no] => DL 17U 6111
        )

)
```

And I want to group it based on `job_card_id` and `registration_no` like:

```
Array(
  [0]=>Array
     (
       [job_card_id] => 1
       [registration_no] => DL 17U 7113
       [repair_order]=>Array
                    (
                     [0]=>Array
                        (
                          [repair_order_id] => 1
                          [customer_request] => test customer request
                          [qty] => 5
                        )
                     [1]=>Array
                        (
                         [repair_order_id] => 2
                         [customer_request] => test customer request1
                          [qty] => 5
                        )
                    )
     )
   [1]=>Array
     (
       [job_card_id] => 2
       [registration_no] => DL 17U 6111
       [repair_order]=>Array
                    (
                     [0]=>Array
                        (
                          [repair_order_id] => 4
                          [customer_request] => test customer request
                          [qty] => 5
                        )
                     [1]=>Array
                        (
                         [repair_order_id] => 5
                         [customer_request] => test customer request1
                         [qty] => 5
                        )
                    )
     )
)
```

How I can produce this type of result,Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply read the first array and write a new one. But seriously have you got some code that you have written to achieve your requirement?

Comment: I new to php and i tried it in many way.But unfortunately I get no success

Comment: SHow us your latest attempt and we will help you with that. If nothing else this will help us use relevant variable names in our attempts at answering

Comment: Don't you think it is the time to accept some answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bu iterate over the your array and create new array:

```
$newArr = [];

foreach($arr as $value)
{
    $key = $value['job_card_id'].$value['registration_no'];
    if (!isset($newArr[$key]))
    {
        $newArr[$key] = [
            'job_card_id' => $value['job_card_id'],
            'registration_no' => $value['registration_no'],
            'repair_order' => [],
        ];
    }
    $newArr[$key]['repair_order'][] = [
        'repair_order_id' => $value['repair_order_id'],
        'customer_request'=> $value['customer_request'],
        'qty' => $value['qty'],
    ];
}
$newArr = array_values($newArr);
```

`$arr` is your array

Comment: Beware, most of the _Do it for me crowd_ also dont bother [accepting answer either](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10179676/anuj-kumar)

Comment: @AnujKumar then accept the answer, don't you? Also should be better to give an answer also to your previous question...